# C# taking two lists of different objects to construct new list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having a slow moment and could use some direction. I have two lists of different objects and I made a separate class that has a constructor taking in those two different objects. I'm trying to figure a way to iterate through my two lists and make a single new list of my new "combined" objects. Would this be done using LINQ maybe? Thanks for your time. Any help is good!

End result is to make an IEnumerable to bind to a listview in xamarin.forms but if I could get a little direction on just creating my new list that would be a big help. Thanks!

```
         List<dbBadges> dbBadgeList = db.Table<dbBadges>().ToList();
         List<dbBadgeProgress> dbBadgeProgress = db.Table<dbBadgeProgress>().ToList();
```

```
public class dabUserBadgeProgress
    {
        dbBadges badge;
        dbBadgeProgress progress;
        public dabUserBadgeProgress(dbBadges badge, dbBadgeProgress progress)
        {
            this.badge = badge;
            this.progress = progress;
        }
```

```
[Table("Badge")]
    public class dbBadges
    {
        [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
        public int badgeId { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public string imageURL { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string method { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public bool visible { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
    }

public class dbBadgeProgress
    {
        [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
        public int id { get; set; }
        //[NotNull]
        public string data { get; set; }
        [Indexed, NotNull]
        public int badgeId { get; set; }
        //[NotNull]
        public double percent { get; set; }
        //[NotNull]
        public int year { get; set; }
        //[NotNull]
        public bool? seen { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need a linq to sql statement with a join between the 2 tables and project that result into a new type. There are plenty of examples out there on how to do this. We can't offer more help without a better understanding of the relationship between the tables as well as the result model.

Comment: how are the two objects correlated?  Do they have a common ID property or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but yeah common id of badgeid. I edited the question to add the different classes.

Comment: Looks like a one-to-many relationship. Again, there are many examples out there on how to query a one to many relationship using linq.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should use [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
var result = dbBadgeList.Join(
    dbBadgeProgress,
    badge => badge.badgeId,
    progress => progress.badgeId,
    (badge, progress) => new dabUserBadgeProgress(badge, progress))
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this which got me the result I was looking for looks like @constphi 's answer would do the same thing.

```
IEnumerable<dabUserBadgeProgress> queryBadges =
            from badge in dbBadgeList
            let badgeid = badge.id
            from progress in dbBadgeProgressList
            let progressbadgeid = progress.badgeId
            where badgeid == progressbadgeid
            select new dabUserBadgeProgress(badge, progress)
            {
                Badge = badge,
                Progress = progress
            };
```